# Functional Programming: Elegant way to read a stream of integers and return the list of those integers

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

This is how I've implemented it in Racket.

```
(define (readInt)
  (define (readIntTail acc)
    (let ([i (read)])
      (if (integer? i) (readIntTail (cons i acc)) (reverse acc) )))
  (readIntTail null))
```

While this works, I was wondering if there exists a more elegant way to do the same. Maybe without using the reverse function.

Comment: `(sequence->list (in-producer read (negate integer?)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cons` the integers without using an accumulator, unless it's a requirement for you to use tail recursion:

```
(define (readInt)
  (let ((x (read)))
    (if (integer? x)
        (cons x (readInt))
        null)))
```

Comment: No, tail recursion wasn't a requirement. Your solution is a much cleaner implementation. Thank you.